# Which Linux command determines if message queues or shared memory are in use?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I would like to know if there is a Linux command to use in the terminal to know if a message queue or shared memory are open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need ipcs. 
You can find more informations there :

- http://www.makelinux.net/alp/035
- http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ipcs8.html